# I have a firewall bridge in pfSense and I want to log only the allowed packet

Tags: bridge, tcpdump, pf, pfsense

I have a `bridge0` which has members `em0` (wan) and `vge0` (lan)

I connect via `ssh` on `vge0`, when I `tcpdump -i pflog0` I get the blocked packets from the bridge0, but when I `tcpdump -i bridge0` I get both the passed and blocked packets from `em0`

How can I tcpdump just the passed packets?

If I `tcpdump -i vge0` I get the ssh/tcpdump traffic too.

My thoughts at this point are to create a "virtual" nic and add it to the `bridge0` and tcpdump on that but the best I have found are dead ends on that.